# Create Play server using activator

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ebean, activator

I am trying to create a new java project with play but I learned to do it with activator (in class), now in my personal computer all I find is to create play project using only SBT and I don't know how to use it and I have a lot of problems like:

I can't get Ebean to work - Says it couldn't find it.
I can't run it - Says it cant find 'javac' although I changed my env variable and add c:\Program File\Java\jdk..\bin to the Path.

I really want to use the regular activator I used in class (which ask you which project you want to build and then you name it, comes with more configuration, at least with the activator I worked.

Can anyone please tell me how can I use activator to create Play server OR how to fix my sbt problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of searches I found the activator run build :)